# How to refresh FragmentTwo from activity of other fragment(FragmentThree)?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am looking for a way to refresh a fragment(FragmentTwo) from the activity in another fragment(FragmentThree). I am working with tabbar and it is preloading next and previous Tabs and therefore not updating views. I have to move two tabs further (FragmentFour or Five) in order to get the FragmentTwo view refreshed. How do I get it refreshed as soon as something is changed in FragmentThree?

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mFragmentListTitles = new ArrayList<>();

public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);

}

@Override public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
@Override public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title){
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentListTitles.add(title);
}

@Override public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

     return mFragmentListTitles.get(position);

}
}
```

FragmentTwo:

```
public class TabFragmentTwo extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_EXAMPLE = "this_is_a_constant";

private String example_data;
private Bundle bundle;
private static ArrayList<SupermarketData> ArrayOfSupermarkets = new ArrayList<>();
private static ArrayList<SupermarketData> ArrayOfSupermarkets2 = new ArrayList<>();
Firebase mRef;
private String PREFS_NAME = "SelectionsSettings";
Context context;

public TabFragmentTwo() {

}

public static TabFragmentTwo newInstance(String example_argument) {
    TabFragmentTwo tabFragmentTwo = new TabFragmentTwo();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_EXAMPLE, example_argument);
    tabFragmentTwo.setArguments(args);
    return tabFragmentTwo;
}

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    example_data = getArguments().getString(ARG_EXAMPLE);
    Log.i("Fragment created with ", example_data);
    bundle = getArguments();
    ArrayOfSupermarkets = TabBarActivity.ArrayOfSupermarkets;
    ArrayOfSupermarkets2 = TabBarActivity.ArrayOfSupermarkets2;
}



int[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.albert_heijn, R.drawable.centrum_mahaai,
        R.drawable.goisco, R.drawable.mangusa, R.drawable.playa_piskado,
        R.drawable.vreugedenhil
};


@Nullable @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Creating the actual gridview
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.supermarket_collection_view, container, false);

    ListAdapter imageAdapterCollectionViewSupermarkets = new ImageAdapterCollectionViewSupermarkets(getActivity(), mThumbIds, ArrayOfSupermarkets);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
    gridview.setAdapter(imageAdapterCollectionViewSupermarkets);

    //Click item in gridview
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You chose: " + ArrayOfSupermarkets.get(position).getSupermarketName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(TabFragmentTwo.this.getActivity(), SupermarketListActivity.class);
            // pass the item information
            intent.putExtra("supermarketName", ArrayOfSupermarkets.get(position).getSupermarketName());
            System.out.print(ArrayOfSupermarkets.get(position).getSupermarketName());
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


    return view;

}

@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);

    mRef = new Firebase("x");

    mRef.child("supermarkets").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            System.out.println("There are " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() + " supermarkets");

            ArrayOfSupermarkets.clear();
            ArrayOfSupermarkets2.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot supermarketSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                SupermarketData supermarket = supermarketSnapshot.getValue(SupermarketData.class);

                SharedPreferences preferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, getContext().MODE_PRIVATE);

                ArrayOfSupermarkets2.add(supermarket);

                if (!preferences.contains(supermarket.getSupermarketName())) {
                    ArrayOfSupermarkets.add(supermarket);
                }
                else {
                    if (preferences.getBoolean(supermarket.getSupermarketName(), false) == true) {
                        ArrayOfSupermarkets.add(supermarket);
                    }
                }

            }

            class supermarketComparator implements Comparator<SupermarketData> {
                public int compare(SupermarketData left, SupermarketData right) {

                    return left.getSupermarketName().compareTo(right.getSupermarketName());
                }
            }
            Collections.sort(ArrayOfSupermarkets, new supermarketComparator());
            Collections.sort(ArrayOfSupermarkets2, new supermarketComparator());

            System.out.println(ArrayOfSupermarkets.get(1).getSupermarketName());
            Log.d("MyTag", "Oke3!");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Log.d("MyTag2", "Something went wrong!!");
        }
    });



    System.out.println("Again!");

    ListAdapter imageAdapterCollectionViewSupermarkets = new ImageAdapterCollectionViewSupermarkets(getActivity(), mThumbIds, ArrayOfSupermarkets);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
    gridview.setAdapter(imageAdapterCollectionViewSupermarkets);

}
}
```

FragmentThree:

```
public class TabFragmentThree extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_EXAMPLE = "this_is_a_constant";
private String example_data;
private static ArrayList<SupermarketData> ArrayOfSupermarkets;
private static ArrayList<SubCategoryData> ArrayOfSubCategories;
private Boolean switchBoolean;



public TabFragmentThree() {

}

public static TabFragmentThree newInstance(String example_argument) {
    TabFragmentThree tabFragmentOne = new TabFragmentThree();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_EXAMPLE, example_argument);
    tabFragmentOne.setArguments(args);
    return tabFragmentOne;
}

@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    example_data = getArguments().getString(ARG_EXAMPLE);
    Log.i("Fragment created with ", example_data);
    ArrayOfSupermarkets = TabBarActivity.ArrayOfSupermarkets2;
    ArrayOfSubCategories = TabBarActivity.ArrayOfSubCategories2;
    switchBoolean = true;


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup     container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selections_view, container, false);

    final ListAdapter customAdapterSelections = new CustomAdapterSelections (getActivity(), ArrayOfSupermarkets, ArrayOfSubCategories, switchBoolean);// Pass the product array to the constructor.
    final ListView customListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.selectionListView);
    customListView.setAdapter(customAdapterSelections);

    final Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.selectionTypeButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            System.out.println("Button");
            if (switchBoolean == true){
                switchBoolean = false;
                button.setText("<- Select Supermarkets");
                ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.selectionsTitleLabel)).setText("Select your Subcategories");
                final ListAdapter customAdapterSelections = new CustomAdapterSelections (getActivity(), ArrayOfSupermarkets, ArrayOfSubCategories, switchBoolean);// Pass the product array to the constructor.
                final ListView customListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.selectionListView);
                customListView.setAdapter(customAdapterSelections);

            }
            else {
                switchBoolean = true;
                button.setText("Select Subcategories ->");
                ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.selectionsTitleLabel)).setText("Select your Supermarkets");
                final ListAdapter customAdapterSelections = new CustomAdapterSelections (getActivity(), ArrayOfSupermarkets, ArrayOfSubCategories, switchBoolean);// Pass the product array to the constructor.
                final ListView customListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.selectionListView);
                customListView.setAdapter(customAdapterSelections);

            }
        }

    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();




}
}
```

CustomAdapterSelections:

```
public class CustomAdapterSelections extends BaseAdapter {

private static final String ARG_EXAMPLE = "this_is_a_constant";
private String example_data;
private ArrayList<SupermarketData> ArrayOfSupermarkets;
private ArrayList<SubCategoryData> ArrayOfSubCategories;
private Context context;
private Boolean switchBoolean = false;
private String PREFS_NAME = "SelectionsSettings";
private String DATA_TAG = "DATA_TAG";
private Boolean data = true;


public CustomAdapterSelections(Context context, ArrayList<SupermarketData> arrayOfSupermarkets, ArrayList<SubCategoryData> arrayOfSubCategories, Boolean switchBoolean) {
    this.context = context;
    this.ArrayOfSupermarkets = arrayOfSupermarkets;
    this.ArrayOfSubCategories = arrayOfSubCategories;
    this.switchBoolean = switchBoolean;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (switchBoolean == true) {
        return ArrayOfSupermarkets.size();
    } else {
        return ArrayOfSubCategories.size();
    }
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.selections_item_row, null);

        System.out.println("Test1");
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        System.out.println("Test2");
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.selectionName);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxSelection);


    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (switchBoolean == true) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    // perform logic
                    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(ArrayOfSupermarkets.get(position).getSupermarketName(), true);
                    editor.commit();
                }
                else {

                    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(ArrayOfSupermarkets.get(position).getSupermarketName(), false);
                    editor.commit();
                }

            }
            else{
                if (isChecked) {
                    // perform logic
                    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(ArrayOfSubCategories.get(position).getProductSubCategory(), true);
                    editor.commit();
                }
                else {

                    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean(ArrayOfSubCategories.get(position).getProductSubCategory(), false);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }

        }


    });


    if (switchBoolean == true) {
        textView.setText(ArrayOfSupermarkets.get(position).getSupermarketName());

        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if(preferences.contains(ArrayOfSupermarkets.get(position).getSupermarketName())) {
            Boolean value = preferences.getBoolean(ArrayOfSupermarkets.get(position).getSupermarketName(), false);
            checkBox.setChecked(value);
        }
        else{
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }





    }
    else{
        textView.setText(ArrayOfSubCategories.get(position).getProductSubCategory());

        SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        if(preferences.contains(ArrayOfSubCategories.get(position).getProductSubCategory())) {
            Boolean value = preferences.getBoolean(ArrayOfSubCategories.get(position).getProductSubCategory(), false);
            checkBox.setChecked(value);
        }
        else {
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
        }

    }




    return view;
}



}
```

Comment: 1 - Create an interface in third fragment
2 - Implement that interface in second fragment in order to update your data

Answer (score 0):

You can use two ways

1. TargetFragment 
   When you go to second fragment to third fragment that time you can add one line.              fragmentTwo.setTargetFragment(CurrentFragment,RequestCode);
   by using TargetFragment you can call public method of second fragment to third fragment
2. interface.
   Create one interface and set in fragment and implement in activity.

Sorry for my english is not good.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried but I can not get the first option to work. Do you have an example of how I should implement this?

Comment: ThirdFragment frag = new ThirdFragment();
Frag. setTargetFragment (this, 0);
getFragmentManager().beginFragmentTransaction().add(R.id.container, frag).addTobackStack(frag.getClass().getSimpleName()).commit()

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution using the insights of this tutorial: Refresh Current Fragment within ViewPager | Android Tutorial and Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8wAZ3uWioTk